# How should be the HTTP timing?

Tags: http, timing

This is the graph of one of my sites https://www.alebalweb-blog.com, first line of firefox development tools -> Network, and I'm not sure that the blocked and waiting entries are "normal".

[image]

Waiting, I suspect it's the server's fault, it's a small vps on Vultr - Ubuntu 18.04, the other day I updated to php7-4-fpm and I haven't activated opcache, memcached, acpu or anything else yet, because (unfortunately) my sites are small, less than a thousand visits a day, and I don't know if it makes sense to activate chace systems, maybe they also affect indexing and positioning on search engines?
Even if yandex and bing give a lot of work for my little server... and maybe just them would take advantage from the cache?

Blocked, it is more confusing, I'm not sure it's me, everything happens before you get to my server? Maybe it's Vultr's fault? Maybe namesilo's fault? (where domains are registered) Maybe mine, some apache configuration or something else? Maybe they're normal values? I have no idea.

Can anyone help me understand if they are normal values? And if they are not, to understand how I can improve?

-------------------------update------------------------

I have read the pages you have suggested to me, even they do not seem to have understood much or found a solution....

I did some things on my little server, like: blocked yandex, enabled opcache, installed memcached.

The intent is to stabilize, to begin to understand something.

I have done many other tests these days, and I have seen results like these:

[image]

[image]

This is another site, but it is on the same server, the one highlighted is matomo (statistics), the tracking javascript script, is in a sub-domain, but always on the same server.

The difference is enormous, and the tests were done within seconds of each other.

So at this point maybe the question is: do you have any suggestions on what else I can do to start understanding something?

At least to understand if to create these timings is me, if it is my server, the scripts of my sites, the browsers, the connection or what else.

Answer (score 1):

None of what you've posted looks very bad, but your service is sometimes taking > 6s to respond to the initial connection request. There are probably a lot of small things wrong that you can fix, I would start with looking at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/784591/ssl-initial-connection-painfully-slow-in-chrome) which addresses the same problem I'm seeing with your site.

Answer (score 1):

The timing looks bit large as for me.
Seems the server is not responding during 150ms (blocked) especially on main page.
Then takes up to 150ms for TLS setup, 200ms to load content etc.

But this is not stable.

Sometimes it took about 800ms to receive homepage, sometimes the whole thing took less then 200ms.

Most likely it is server issues (as your virtual server share physical hardware machine with other servers).

And just for reference:

[What does "Blocked" really mean in the Firefox developer tools Network monitoring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783829/what-does-blocked-really-mean-in-the-firefox-developer-tools-network-monitorin)

Also, there is some general things to consider as troubleshoot:

I suggest to create local (localhost) version of the site, then:

1. Check time actually required to render homepage (inside server log)
2. Temporary remove gzip compression
3. Temporary remove https
4. Temporary remove output buffering in php (hope your code does not need it)
5. Check if any "post processing" content hooks are active in php