# Axios taking long time to fetch response

Tags: reactjs, django, api, heroku, axios

I am using Axios instance in a React app to fetch data from GET requests. Backend server is deployed on Heroku(Professional Dyno) and written in Django REST framework. Database is deployed on AWS.

On postman, APIs are giving response in around 2-3 seconds:
[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IL8U.png)

But in the react app, response time is around 25-30 seconds.
[React app response time Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1Fbk.png)

Please note that I am calling around 10 different APIs in a single page. Is this affecting the response times?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your request got blocked for 18 seconds. When you are executing multiple heavy requests, it's definitely possible that this requests takes some time to be even executed. If you want to check whether this is the reason for it, you could just comment out the other requests an examine what happens.

An interesting request on what blocked means can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783829/what-does-blocked-really-mean-in-the-firefox-developer-tools-network-monitorin).

Comment: Yes I tried it.
It shows a little improvement, but now the waiting time is showing between 10-15 secs
@emrich